# Ребрендинг Android приложения

Tags: android, маркетинг

Год назад запустил Android приложение. Было пару положительных публикаций, но подвела реализация - было много ошибок и негативных отзывов. За этот год довел приложение до ума (надеюсь **:)**). Общее количество скачек от 5-10 тысяч, оценка в магазине 4.2, ежедневное количество скачиваний 5-10. Активных пользователей несколько сотен. Хочу осуществить перезапуск приложения:

- меняю название
- добавляю новые функции
- новая история приложения
- изменяю модель монетизации - подписка.

Теперь собственно вопрос - перезапуск лучше осуществлять в рамках существующего приложения, или создать новое приложение? Интуиция подсказывает что это очень важный момент. Буду благодарен за любые советы и информацию.

Comment: Какая сейчас модель монетизации?

Comment: Сейчас приложение поддерживает несколько платформ - Android, Windows 10, Windows Phone. На каждой платформе  полная версия приложения платная - хочу перевести на подписку.

Comment: Прямо-таки Adobe с переходом от Creative Suite к Creative Cloud. После того, как они окончательно перешли на подписку, конкуренты оживились и добавили в свои преимущества "не подписка, покупается однажды".

Comment: Конкуренты  используют подписку. Т.е здесь или подписка все платформы доступны или пользователю покупать для каждой платформы - что тоже вызывает вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Мое субъективное мнение с точки зрения пользователя.

Если бы я пользовался какой-либо программой, которую купил в свое время, а затем ее перевели на подписку, то вероятнее всего пользоваться ею перестал бы. В данном случае мне, как пользователю, видится 2 варианта развития событий:

1. Прежний функционал остается доступным, я могу продолжать пользоваться программой, но новый функционал доступен по подписке.
2. Появляется новая программа с подпиской, которая покрывает функционал старой и предлагает новые функции. Я оцениваю потребности и либо продолжаю пользоваться уже купленной, либо перехожу на новую с подпиской (если я новый пользователь, то также оценю что мне необходимо и либо куплю разово, либо буду пользоваться программой с подпиской). При этом в старой программе можно напоминать пользователю, что есть более продвинутая программа, переходите на нее.

В общем, такие идеи. Но решать только Вам.

Comment: Для пользователей которые купили приложение предоставлю подписку бесплатно(на год). Для меня сейчас более важный момент это "информационный выхлоп" от перезапуска. В существующей версии - есть определенная позиция по поисковым запросам, и оценкам, в новом приложении этого еще нет.